# Python's filter functions arguments order

Tags: python, parameter-passing, idioms

Python's [filter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) and [itertools.ifilter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.ifilter) functions has the next signatures:

```
filter(function, iterable)
itertools.ifilter(predicate, iterable)
```

Is there any reason to place the `predicate` argument before `iterable`? In such case one cannot skip `predicate` argument to simplify `filter(bool, [0, 1, 0, 2])` call to just `filter([0, 1, 0, 2])`. The second one for me looks more idiomatic.

Comment: The second does not make any sense. Filtering a list with no predicate? How would that even work? Remember that explicit is better than implicit (`import this`).

Comment: @VincentSavard: Strangely enough, there's actually a defined behavior for filtering with no predicate. If you pass `None` as the predicate, it works the same as passing `bool` or `lambda x: x`.

Comment: @user2357112: Eww, that's disappointing. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Probably because functions like map, filter, and reduce come out of the tradition of functional programming, so filter took its argument order from those. For map and reduce, this argument order makes more sense, though I'm sympathetic to your argument about filter alone.

Comment: It makes sense for partial application: `even_filter = functools.partial(itertools.ifilter, lambda x: x % 2 == 0); foo = even_filter(foo)`

Comment: @VincentSavard You might want a filter which doesn't filter.

Comment: @chepner: That's different, you're making a function by partially applying the predicate, not the list. Plus, it's not really idiomatic in Python.

Comment: @chepner, sounds very reasonable.

Comment: Also, in the functional world, you can think of `filter` as a function which takes a single argument (the filter function) and returns a *new* function which takes a list as an argument and returns a filtered list. Currying blurs the line between `filter(func, iterable)` and `filter(func)(iterable)`.

Comment: @VincentSavard But it's another application of functional programming which is what was shoe-horned into the language along with `map`, `reduce`, `filter`, and `lambda`, which is why it's relevant: http://python-history.blogspot.com/2009/04/origins-of-pythons-functional-features.html

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist: I think it's very far outside the scope of this question in its current state, which is why I think it's _not_ relevant here. The question is pretty much "Why doesn't the `predicate` argument have a default value"

Comment: The simple answer is "`filter` has the same argument order in other languages". Everything else is relevant to the question of why that order exists in the first place.

Comment: @chepner: You can answer that historically, `filter`'s arguments are in this order because it facilitates partial application. But you can't justify the behaviour of `filter([0, 1, 0, 2])` with partial application.

Comment: I'm not trying to. `filter([0,1,0,2])` is simply wrong, and the OP specifically points out that you *can't* do this with the actual definition of `filter`. Since `def filter(list, function=None)` *would* allow you to omit the default predicate instead of using `filter(None, [0,1,0,2])`, the OP is asking why the function is defined as it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It helps to understand the paradigm from which `filter` was borrowed. Rather than thinking of `filter` as a function that takes a function and a list as two arguments, think of it as a function that takes a single argument, the predicate. The return value is a *new* function, one that takes a list and returns a new list. In this sense, `filter` is a function (really, a functor) that "lifts" a function into a new "category".

For example, suppose you have a predicate `is_even`, that takes an integer as its argument and returns true if the argument is even, false if it is odd. Then `filter(is_even)` can be thought of as returning a function that takes a *list* of integers and returning a *list* of booleans, each element indicating the evenness of the corresponding input item. You could apply that function to a list, so that `filter(is_even)(list_of_ints)` is identical to `filter(is_even, list_of_ints)` in Python. This method of decomposing a multiargument function into a series of single-argument functions is called *currying*.

`filter`'s type signature reflects its origins and Python's lack of built-in currying. You can simulate this using `functools.partial`, which allows you to partially apply a function by providing arguments from left to right for the defined parameters.

```
from functools import partial
x = partial(filter, is_even)  # lambda lst: filter(is_even, lst)
new_list = x(list_of_ints)
# or just new_list = partial(filter, is_even)(list_of_ints)
```